# Brain fog on calorie restriction

Tags: diet

I am trying to go on a cut and started reducing my calorie intake. Immediately my lifts started going down, and most of the day, I seem to have brain fog which makes it very difficult to get by the dya.

Could someone advice me how I could control the negative effects of a cut?

Comment: How much did you cut?

Comment: Probably halved my intake? @DeeV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much of a caloric drop you are doing, but the begging of a cut usually feels fine, and lifts can still go up during the first two weeks depending on experience.

You seem to be experiencing near full three day fasting symptoms, so the only way to break it down more is to look at your maintenance versus what you’re currently doing.

Comment: "break it down more"

Comment: Unless you are in a huge surplus, or a behemoth with low body fat.. any thing below 4000 calories halved is a severe cut. To put into perspective, the week before a show most body builders are on 1600. So the side affects from your cut, are from such a low, and drastic change.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're getting an adequate amount of protein to support muscle maintenance and recovery during your cut.  ensure you're still getting a balanced mix of carbohydrates and fats. You might need to reduce the intensity or frequency of your workouts temporarily to avoid burnout.